# I need to show a popup message when I push button when a specific button is enable in aspx

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a project and I am having a hard time with it. I need to finish it by tomorrow so I need  your help , please.
The problem is that I have a website has a button called Edit. The user has to click the button to show him two buttons one called Save and the other one Cancel and there is another button on the webpage called Submit Hours to chair. The user has to enter the hours first and save them then press the Submit button.
If the user did not save and press the Submit button the popup message tells him that needs to put the hour and save first.
Here is the Code

This code is for SUbmit button

`<asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmitChair" runat="server" Text="Submit Schedule to Chair" 
               SkinID="AspButton" onclick="ButtonSubmitChair_Click"/>`

protected void ButtonSubmitChair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
             objMs.UpdateStatus("SC", Convert.ToInt32(Session["FacId"]), Convert.ToInt32(Session["TermId"]));
            DetailsViewMainSchedule.DataBind();
            GvTeachingSchedule.DataBind();
            GvResearchSchedule.DataBind();
            OfficeHoursGridView.DataBind();
            GridViewOffCampus.DataBind();
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
            UpdatePaneloffcamp.Update();
            UpdatePanel3.Update();
            //ButtonSubmitChair.Enabled = GetSubmitButtonStatus();
            ButtonSubmitChair.Enabled = false; //RZL added to disable button

```
        string facmail = "";
        string facname = "";

        DataTable dt1 = objF.GetFacultyEmailId(Convert.ToInt32(Session["FacId"]));
        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            facmail = dt1.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
            facname = dt1.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();

        }
        DataTable dt = objF.GetChairEmail(Convert.ToInt32(Session["DeptID"]));
        string chairname = "";
        string chairmail = "";

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            chairname = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
            chairmail = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
        }
        string FacultyComments = ((TextBox)(DetailsViewMainSchedule.FindControl("TextBoxFCItem"))).Text;
        string ChairComments = ((TextBox)(DetailsViewMainSchedule.FindControl("TextBoxCCItem"))).Text;
        string DeanComments = ((TextBox)(DetailsViewMainSchedule.FindControl("TextBoxDCItem"))).Text;
        if (FacultyComments == "")
            FacultyComments = "No Comments";
        if (ChairComments == "")
            ChairComments = "No Comments";
        if (DeanComments == "")
            DeanComments = "No Comments";

        try
        {
            objM.message(facname, chairname, FacultyComments, ChairComments, DeanComments, chairmail, facmail, "sc");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect("schedule.aspx?" + pageQueryString);
        }
```

}`

1. here is the Edit 
   aspx
   `<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                          CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="<%# GetEditStatus() %>"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate><EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSave" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                          CommandName="Update" Text="Save"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                          CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton></EditItemTemplate><InsertItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonInsert" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                          CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" onclick="LinkButtonInsert_Click"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtoncancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                          CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton></InsertItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>`
   enter code here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ModalPopup, just set the codebehind to display the Popup if there's an error, otherwise, submit!

http://everymanprogrammer.com/index.php/using-the-ajax-modalpopup-a-beginners-guide/

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond. I thought to use If statement if save button is visible then show the message. I have had a hard time how to do this. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a Session var like
     Session("isSaved")= true

when the user hits Save.  The Submit button would look like

```
if not Session("isSaved")= true then 
    modalForm.Show
else
    'DoSubmit
end if
```